# Python os.path.join() mangling absolute path in Windows

Tags: python, python-2.7, path

I'm new to Python and I'm trying to access a file with a full path represented by the following:

```
'X:/01 File Folder/MorePath/Data/Test/myfile.txt'
```

Every time I try to build the full string using `os.path.join`, it ends up slicing out everything between the drive letter and the second path string, like so:

```
import os
basePath = 'X:/01 File Folder/MorePath'
restofPath = '/Data/Test/myfile.txt'
fullPath = os.path.join(basePath,restofPath)
```

gives me:

```
'X:/Data/Test/myfile.txt'
```

as the `fullPath` name.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Does it have something to do with the digits near the beginning of the base path name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `/` at the beginning of your `restofPath` means "start at the root directory." So `os.path.join()` helpfully does that for you.

If you don't want it to do that, write your `restofPath` as a relative directory, i.e., `Data/Test/myfile.txt`, rather than an absolute one.

If you are getting your `restofPath` from somewhere outside your program (user input, config file, etc.), and you always want to treat it as relative even if the user is so gauche as to start the path with a slash, you can use `restofPath.lstrip(r"\/")`.

Comment: Thank you, now I feel like an idiot. :) At least I can stop pulling my hair out now. I'll accept when SO lets me after the 10 minute window.